# Use Cases: separate or not?

Tags: uml, use-case

Should I make two separate use cases if a Member of the website can View their own personal profile and those of other users? Should it be Member - View Own Profile and Member-View Others' Profile? Or just Member - View Profile is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments, An use case can have one complete scenario/feature/function of the application. Hence if you are talking about use-case of member viewing profile, then it will be one use case but if you are talking about test cases for verification, then it would be two test cases.

A member viewing own profile does not mean that he can view others profiles too. Hence you need to have two test cases for verifying both the possibilities.

On the other hand, there are few more cases in this too - you should have cases like member able to edit his profile, edit others profile and this can also go to individual fields too. Member being able to edit all his details, but able to edit few details of other particular members below him in hierarchy and should not be able to edit any details of other members above him in hierarchy etc.

Comment: Use cases are not features, check the literature (e.g. Bittner).

Comment: @Gabriel - Well, not sure if that deserved a downvote. Anyway I have edited to change "features" to "scenarios". Hope this seems fine?

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag the problem is not in words (although use cases represent a set of scenarios, not a specific one), but in contents. Use cases as said help to achieve a certain goal for an actor. This means, that every separate use case should have value for the actor. Imagine that the sole purpose (and the behaviour) of the web app would be to show a Member his information. Would such an app help you in any way? Would you pay for it? One might require login screen for authentication and authorization, but that is a feature, not an use case, no onw would pay for an app which allows to log in.

Comment: @Gabriel - Tough I am not clear on what you are trying to tell me, I want to know how is this related to the given question and my answer to it? I am not getting what exactly is wrong. I have only answered in simple terms saying OP has to keep two seperate usecases for his testing. Sorry. Please help me a little more in understanding this. You might be right, but I am not getting it. ;)

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag I am saying, OP has to decide according to his problem and separation as you suggested is probably a wrong answer. The reason is that such separation will give no benefit. The point of use cases is to describe what system should and should not do. Every behaviour can be split in smaller pieces and therefore an use case should be as high level as it gets. I think your answer gives no benefit, just more work to describe the same behaviour. In previous comment I described the reasoning used to identify the right level of an use case.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag ...my first comment about features was a note on features being lower level than use cases should be and therefore your reasoning to have use case for a feature is wrong.

Comment: @Gabriel - I think there is slight confusion in terms probably. I should've used testcase instead of usecase. Think thats where the confusion is. Thanks mate. Use cases are set of testcases. The OP can have one use-case with two testcases for his scenario.

Comment: @Gabriel - Finally edited the answer as per comments and our discussion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the three use cases, like this:
[image: Use cases]

Comment: Use cases are not for structuring the functionality. Use cases are for analysis, not design of the system.

Comment: Don't you use the scenarios inside the use cases to identify the classes, attributes and actions?, I knew that it was allowed to factorize a use case when it was part of more than one use cases, so you don't have to repeat scenarios.

Comment: you mention scenarios, but I will call them use case descriptions, because a scenario is an example of one particular flow through an use case. These descriptions are indeed used just as you say, however they don't include those design elements. Those

Comment: Those are part of use case realisations (visualised using e.g. sequence UML diagrams). The include relationship is indeed for avoiding repetition. However if you have not written the description, how can you know this would help? I guess one use case "View user profile" would be much less effort to describe than those three. And finally there is that point of use case helping to achieve an actor its goal and thereby giving it some value. Would you buy an app which allows you just to select an user? For more see my comments above.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I should have in mind that the use case is a goal that the actor needs to achieve the next time I do use cases, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Use cases demonstrate how actors use the system to achieve their goals. So structuring of use cases must adhere to these goals. Would you say, that an actor, e.g. visitor of your web app, would use your appication just to view his profile? Would he use it just to view profile some other user? If those are separate goals, then the use cases should be separate. But if you want to allow a visitor to see information about other users on site, one use case suffices.